# Getting an error "could not find method implementation()" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting this ERROR message.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':app']
>   on object  of type 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Here's my project level's gradle file :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app')
}
```

Here's my app's gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.therationalbloke.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation project(':app')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

NOTE : I'm already aware of the following.

- The "compile" has been replaced by "implementation" in Gradle 3.0 or
  higher.
- Yes, I'm using Android Studio's latest version and according to Rob, I should prefer the old one. But the thing is that I was haunted
  by a lot of technical issues in that version (a lot of them included
  stuff which is now outdated).
- I've read almost every solution to this problem on Stack Overflow, Github. All of them are either asking to use implementation() instead
  of compile (which I'm already using), or they're asking to check if
  the Gradle version is 3.0+.
- I've tried changing all the "implementation" to "compile" on suggestion of one user on Stackoverflow.
- I've tried importing a lot of libraries as suggested by a lot of people in different communities.

**Some info about my Android Studio**

- Android Studio - 3.1.3
- Android Plugin Version - 3.1.3
- Gradle Version - 4.4

[Screenshot of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gWTF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen something like `implementation project(':app')` on a gradle file.

Here you have an example of a working gradle file, try deleting `implementation project(':app')` and resync.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.amvt_notebook4.codigoqrtest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies
{
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation files('build/libs/mail.jar')
  implementation files('build/libs/additionnal.jar')
  implementation files('build/libs/activation.jar')
  implementation files('build/libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: There are two gradle files. One is the project level gradle file and the other is app's gradle file. I think here, you're referring to the project level gradle file in which
 "implementation project(':app')" is written.
I removed this part, i.e. "dependencies { implementation project(':app') }" from the project level gradle file and synced again.

The error that I was getting vanished, but now I'm getting a new error.
It is : "The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins."

Here's the screenshot of my screen right now.
http://prntscr.com/k23cba